# Hough circle transform python

Tags: python, image-processing, edge-detection, hough-transform

I'm tried to implement Hough :

```
import math
from math import exp

import cv2.cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import ndimage


def imReadAndConvert(filename: str, representation: int) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Reads an image, and returns the image converted as requested
    :param filename: The path to the image
    :param representation: GRAY_SCALE or RGB
    :return: The image object
    """
    # Open the img file

    if representation == 2:
        image = cv.imread(filename, 1)
        data = np.asarray(image, dtype=np.float32)
        data = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    else:
        image = cv.imread(filename, 0)
        data = np.asarray(image, dtype=np.float32)

    return data


def conv1D(inSignal: np.ndarray, kernel1: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Convolve a 1-D array with a given kernel
    :param inSignal: 1-D array
    :param kernel1: 1-D array as a kernel
    :return: The convolved array
    """
    k = kernel1[::-1]
    a = np.pad(inSignal, (len(k) - 1, len(k) - 1), 'constant')
    res = np.zeros(len(a) - len(k) + 1)
    for i in range(0, len(a) - len(k) + 1):
        res[i] = np.multiply(a[i:i + len(k)], k).sum()

    return res


def conv2D(inImage: np.ndarray, kernel2: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Convolve a 2-D array with a given kernel
    :param inImage: 2D image
    :param kernel2: A kernel
    :return: The convolved image
    """
    k = np.flip(kernel2)
    print(inImage.shape)
    a = np.pad(inImage, (k.shape[0] // 2, k.shape[1] // 2), 'edge')
    res = np.ndarray(inImage.shape)
    for i in range(res.shape[0]):
        for j in range(res.shape[1]):
            res[i, j] = np.multiply(a[i:i + k.shape[0], j:j + k.shape[1]], k).sum()

    return res


def convDerivative(inImage: np.ndarray) -> (np.ndarray, np.ndarray, np.ndarray, np.ndarray):
    """
    Calculate gradient of an image
    :param inImage: Grayscale iamge
    :return: (directions, magnitude,x_der,y_der)
    """

    k = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0],
                  [0, -1, 0]])
    Ix = conv2D(inImage, k.transpose())
    Iy = conv2D(inImage, k)
    mag = np.sqrt(np.power(Ix, 2) + np.power(Iy, 2))
    div = np.arctan2(Iy, Ix)
    return div, mag, Ix, Iy


def blurImage1(in_image: np.ndarray, kernel_size: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Blur an image using a Gaussian kernel
    :param inImage: Input image
    :param kernelSize: Kernel size
    :return: The Blurred image
    """

    gaussian = np.ndarray(kernel_size)
    sigma = 0.3 * ((kernel_size[0] - 1) * 0.5 - 1) + 0.8
    for x in range(0, kernel_size[0]):
        for y in range(0, kernel_size[1]):
            gaussian[x, y] = math.exp(-((x ** 2 + y ** 2) / (2.0 * sigma ** 2))) / (math.pi * (sigma ** 2) * 2)
    return conv2D(in_image, gaussian)


def blurImage2(in_image: np.ndarray, kernel_size: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Blur an image using a Gaussian kernel using OpenCV built-in functions
    :param inImage: Input image
    :param kernelSize: Kernel size
    :return: The Blurred image
    """

    sigma = 0.3 * ((kernel_size[0] - 1) * 0.5 - 1) + 0.8
    shape = (kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1])
    res = cv.GaussianBlur(in_image, shape, sigma)
    return res


def edgeDetectionSobel(img: np.ndarray, thresh: float = 0.2) -> (np.ndarray, np.ndarray):
    """
    Detects edges using the Sobel method
    :param img: Input image
    :param thresh: The minimum threshold for the edge response
    :return: opencv solution, my implementation
    """
    s = np.array([[1, 0, -1],
                  [2, 0, -2],
                  [1, 0, -1]])

    thresh *= 255
    my_res = np.sqrt((conv2D(img, s) ** 2 + conv2D(img, s.transpose()) ** 2))
    my = np.ndarray(my_res.shape)
    my[my_res > thresh] = 1
    my[my_res < thresh] = 0
    plt.imshow(my, cmap='gray')
    plt.show()

    cv_res = cv.magnitude(cv.Sobel(img, -1, 1, 0), cv.Sobel(img, -1, 0, 1))
    v = np.ndarray(cv_res.shape)
    v[cv_res > thresh] = 1
    v[cv_res < thresh] = 0

    plt.imshow(v, cmap='gray')
    plt.show()
    return cv_res, my_res


def edgeDetectionZeroCrossingSimple(img: np.ndarray) -> (np.ndarray):
    """
    Detecting edges using the "ZeroCrossing" method
    :param I: Input image
    :return: Edge matrix
    """
    k = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
                  [1, -4, 1],
                  [0, 1, 0]])
    d = conv2D(img, k)
    res = np.zeros(d.shape)

    for i in range(0, d.shape[0]):
        for j in range(0, d.shape[1]):
            try:
                if d[i, j] == 0:
                    if (d[i, j + 1] > 0 and d[i, j - 1] < 0) or (d[i, j + 1] < 0 and d[i, j - 1] > 0) or (
                            d[i + 1, j] > 0 and d[i - 1, j] < 0) or (d[i + 1, j] < 0 and d[i - 1, j] > 0):
                        res[i, j] = 1
                elif d[i, j] > 0:
                    if d[i, j + 1] < 0 or d[i + 1, j] < 0:
                        res[i, j] = 1
                else:
                    if d[i, j + 1] > 0 or d[i + 1, j] > 0:
                        res[i, j] = 1

            except IndexError as e:
                pass
    return res


def edgeDetectionZeroCrossingLOG(img: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Detecting edges using the "ZeroCrossingLOG" method
    :param I: Input image
    :return: :return: Edge matrix
    """
    blur = blurImage2(img, np.array([5, 5]))
    return edgeDetectionZeroCrossingSimple(blur)


def sobleForCanny(img: np.ndarray):
    Kx = np.array([[-1, 0, 1],
                   [-2, 0, 2],
                   [-1, 0, 1]])
    Ky = np.array([[1, 2, 1],
                   [0, 0, 0],
                   [-1, -2, -1]])

    Ix = conv2D(img, Kx)
    Iy = conv2D(img, Ky)
    print(Ix)
    G = np.sqrt(np.power(Ix, 2) + np.power(Iy, 2))
    theta = np.arctan2(Iy, Ix)
    return G, theta


def edgeDetectionCanny(img: np.ndarray, thrs_1: float, thrs_2: float) -> (np.ndarray, np.ndarray):
    """
    Detecting edges usint "Canny Edge" method
    :param img: Input image
    :param thrs_1: T1
    :param thrs_2: T2
    :return: opencv solution, my implementation
    """

    mag, div = sobleForCanny(img)
    nms = non_max_suppression(mag, div)

    for i in range(0, nms.shape[0]):
        for j in range(0, nms.shape[1]):
            try:
                if nms[i][j] <= thrs_2:
                    nms[i][j] = 0
                elif thrs_2 < nms[i][j] < thrs_1:
                    neighbor = nms[i - 1:i + 2, j - 1: j + 2]
                    if neighbor.max() < thrs_1:
                        nms[i][j] = 0
                    else:
                        nms[i][j] = 255
                else:
                    nms[i][j] = 255
            except IndexError as e:
                pass

    cvc = cv.Canny(img.astype(np.uint8), thrs_1, thrs_2)
    return cvc, nms


def non_max_suppression(img: np.ndarray, D: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    M, N = img.shape
    Z = np.zeros((M, N), dtype=np.float32)
    angle = D * 180. / np.pi
    angle[angle < 0] += 180

    for i in range(1, M - 1):
        for j in range(1, N - 1):
            try:
                q = 255
                r = 255
                # angle 0
                if (0 <= angle[i, j] < 22.5) or (157.5 <= angle[i, j] <= 180):
                    q = img[i, j + 1]
                    r = img[i, j - 1]
                # angle 45
                elif 22.5 <= angle[i, j] < 67.5:
                    q = img[i + 1, j - 1]
                    r = img[i - 1, j + 1]
                # angle 90
                elif 67.5 <= angle[i, j] < 112.5:
                    q = img[i + 1, j]
                    r = img[i - 1, j]
                # angle 135
                elif 112.5 <= angle[i, j] < 157.5:
                    q = img[i - 1, j - 1]
                    r = img[i + 1, j + 1]

                if (img[i, j] >= q) and (img[i, j] >= r):
                    Z[i, j] = img[i, j]
                else:
                    Z[i, j] = 0

            except IndexError as e:
                pass

    return Z


def houghCircle(img: np.ndarray, min_radius: float, max_radius: float) -> list:
    """
    Find Circles in an image using a Hough Transform algorithm extension
    :param I: Input image
    :param minRadius: Minimum circle radius
    :param maxRadius: Maximum circle radius
    :return: A list containing the detected circles,
    [(x,y,radius),(x,y,radius),...]
    """

    div, _, _, _ = convDerivative(img)
    div = div * 180. / np.pi
    div[div < 0] += 180
    cvc, img = edgeDetectionCanny(img, 100, 30)
    plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
    plt.show()
    plt.imshow(cvc, cmap='gray')
    plt.show()
    tresh = 10
    hough = np.ndarray((img.shape[0], img.shape[1], max_radius - min_radius))
    list = []

    for r in range(hough.shape[2]):
        for x in range(45, img.shape[0]):
            for y in range(250, img.shape[1]):
                if img[x, y] == 255:
                    try:
                        t1 = div[x, y]
                        t2 = div[x, y] - 180
                        a1 = x - round((r + min_radius) * np.cos(t1 * math.pi / 180))
                        b1 = y - round((r + min_radius) * np.sin(t1 * math.pi / 180))
                        a2 = x - round((r + min_radius) * np.cos(t2 * math.pi / 180))
                        b2 = y - round((r + min_radius) * np.sin(t2 * math.pi / 180))
                        hough[int(a1), int(b1), r] += 1
                        hough[int(a2), int(b2), r] += 1
                        # if hough[int(a1), int(b1), r] > tresh:
                        #     list.append((a1, b1, r))
                        # if hough[int(a2), int(b2), r] > tresh:
                        #     list.append((a2, b2, r))
                    except IndexError as e:
                        pass

    for r in range(hough.shape[2]):
        for x in range(0, img.shape[0]):
            for y in range(0, img.shape[1]):

                if hough[x, y, r] > tresh:
                    list.append((x, x, r))

    return list


image = imReadAndConvert("coins.jpg", 1)
center_coordinates = (300, 50)

# Radius of circle
radius = 20
# Blue color in BGR
color = (0, 0, 255)
# Line thickness of 2 px
thickness = 2
image = cv.circle(image, center_coordinates, radius, color, thickness)

plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
plt.show()

list = houghCircle(image, 10, 30)
print(list)
```

it seems like it's not giving me any circle, I tried to calculate all the 360 degrees of each point and mark all the center points that are 'r' away from it...

but only if the point is already marked as 1 from canny.

I'm not 100% about the math but it's from :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_Hough_Transform

What is wrong with the logic?

Sample img:
[image]

Comment: I think you need to do all the counting in one complete pass through the pixels, and only once that has finished do a pass through the counts looking for locations with score > thresh.

Comment: Also you need to make sure that each of the 360 degrees is hitting a different location so you don’t put multiple counts into one location. Better to do a pixel-wise step around the circle than to do the 360 degrees cos/sin calculation because also then you don’t miss locations on the circle.

Comment: But I'm not looking for the current location circle, I need to find to the center points of all the circles the current x,y pixel is on.
So I add to the center ++ and only if it passes the thresh it will be considered as a circle

Comment: You only know it passes the threshold after you’ve counted all the contributions to that location, because it’s only once you have added contributions from all the points on the circle that the high count>thresh indicates the hough location is the centre.

Comment: Please provide the sample image you’re trying to detect circles in, and a complete [mre]

Comment: Note that your code adds threshold detection within the innermost loop that isn’t indicated in the pseudo-code in the wikipedia article you link, which IMO is very much “pseudo” code. You also added the `t1` and `t2` stuff which seems completely off-piste as they are the same value - so each hough location (a1,b1) and the same location (a2,b2) gets incremented twice.

Comment: Ok I have added and also tried to improve the algorithm, still not results.. @barny

Comment: I would happily run your code to try find out what's wrong, but it's _still_ not a [mre]. I don't have the faintest idea how to load that image into a numpy array - you've got the code, please add it. Please include the import statements, because I don't know where e.g. edgeDetectionCanny comes from and why should I guess because I might guess wrong - I need to be able to paste your code into a .py file and run it _without adding anything_ except perhaps to fix the filename of the jpg file.

Comment: @barny so I have added all the extra functions and all the new details still not working...
I think it's in the formula I don't get the right center of the circle

Comment: I thought I was pretty clear in what I said last time, but I went to the effort of copy/paste the various bits of code into a file and **it doesn't run**. Try it for yourself: copy/paste the various pieces from this question into a file, and get it to run. **Then** come back and paste the exact code you got to run into your question preferably as one piece of code i.e. without bits of text between sections of code. Last chance for me to help. BTW last time I said "include the import statements" and you didn't. **Please include everything including the import statements with your full code**

Comment: I have added all my code with small test at the end ( creating a small circle on the coin image) the last function is the hough @barny